# jQuery $.post problem with emails

Tags: jquery, email, .post

I'm trying to post form data in a lightbox through jQuery and php.  There are only 3 field values I need to pass.  I do not get any errors on submit, but the emails aren't sending.  I'm noticing (through Firebug) that the email addresses that are being entered into a textbox (which are the email addresses the form sends to) are being sent as: '%40' instead of '@'.  Has anyone experienced this or know why/how to fix this issue?
My jQuery function is as follows:

```
$('#notify form').submit(function(){
  $.post('path/to/action/to/send/email', { id: $("#id").val(), client_reviews: $("#client_reviewers").val(), client_reviewers_msg: $("#client_reviewers_msg").val() }, function(){
  tb_remove();
  $('#client_reviewers').val('');
  $('#client_reviewers_msg').val('');
});
return false;
```

});

thanks in advance for any help.
j

Comment: What parameter contains the email address(es)?  What does the form tag look like?  Have you tried returning false from your submit handler (the function you posted)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing is [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding).

Basically, the `@` is a special character in a URL. So when you submit a field with a special character in it, it has to be escaped. This is most useful in a GET request where the field values actually end up in the URL, but a POST request follows the same rules.

In PHP, you can use the [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function to decode this.

Answer (score 0):

%40 is the URL representation of the @ sign. You'll need to URLDecrypt the email in php.